# MSBuild not working for a console application on build server

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I am running MSBuild with a specific set of parameters and it is not finding an entry point, but is able to run fine in Visual Studio.

The .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>  
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x86</Platforms>       
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>     
  </PropertyGroup>
```

There is a program main:

```
public static void Main()
```

... MSBuild is run as follows, to produce a console application:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" 
    ".\Project.csproj" 
    /p:OutputPath=C:\temp\outputpath 
    /property:Configuration=Release 
    /property:OutputType=exe 
    /p:PlatformTarget=x86
```

However, on our build server, as the git runner, this produces the following error:

> CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method
> suitable for an entry point [... path to another .netstandard "class
> library" project referenced by the console app in the solution, not
> the console app itself]

Note that the error doesn't refer to the main application of the project, but one of the referenced library projects.

UPDATE/EDIT:
This problem is solved by simply adding `Program.cs` with an empty `public static void Main() {}` to both the *class library* dependent projects of this console application.  It seems nonsensical, but that does make the issue go away.  The question is - why is this necessary?

Comment: Do the versions of Visual Studio, MSBuild, .NET SDK etc. match between the two?

Comment: @MartinCostello almost exactly - the failing one has the MSBuild path you see in the question, in the VS community edition folder ... the working one has enterprise VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a quirk of MSBuild shipping with VS community edition 2019 building a `net472` project which had project references to 2 x `netstandard2.0` class libraries.

The solution was to add an empty entry point into those 2 class libraries, which seems nonsensical - but solved the problem completely:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main() { }
}
```

It seems that when outputting a console application (`outputType:exe` as opposed to `outputType:winexe`), this is necessary.

Just to re-iterate, there was *aready* an entry point into the actual console application, but for some reason this was *also* required in the class libraries it referenced.  If any of the heavyweights on here can explain this, it would be very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when no static Main method with a correct signature is found in the code that produces an executable file. Also occurs if the entry point function, Main, is defined with the wrong case, such as lowercase main. For information about the rules that apply to the Main method, see Main () and Command Line Arguments.

You have probably to define a class and then insert a main method inside

Comment: This is all correct, but it doesn't answer the question and suggests that you haven't fully read the question.  Take another look - you'll see that I posted the definition of `Main()` and stated there is a program class.

Comment: I will partially take this back and assume you were talking about the dependent class library projects that were referenced by the console application I was referring to above.  But I can't mark the answer as correct because this is a not-logical solution.  A dependent class library shouldn't need an entry point when the main referencing host app already has that.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `OutputType` on the command line. In MSBuild, command line arguments take precedence over any properties set in the project file (if you check the build logs you should find the message `The "OutputType" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.` whenever MSBuild encounters an attempt to set the property in a project file).

The command line arguments are also passed to any project that is being built as a transitive dependency. So MSBuild is trying to build your library project as an exe project, leading the complaint about a missing entry point.

You don't actually need to specify the output type on the command line since it is already specified in the console app project file. Just try removing it.

Comment: Actually this was going wrong *before* the output type was added to the command line - removing it didn't work.  The only thing that worked was what I described in the solution I posted above ☝️ ...